# I have a 3D numpy array. I want to flatten slices of it and then turn it back into the same 3D array. How can I do that?(python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I basically have a numpy array of shape (9400,20,30).

I want to take slices of 200 2-Dimensional arrays (Shape = (200,20,30)) and then flatten those to do some calculations.

Then I want to turn the array back to my original (9400,20,30) shape.

Any help is welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should slice it and reshape it like this:

```
smallArray = bigArray[:200]
bigArray = bigArray[200:]
print(f'bigArray sliced shape: {np.shape(bigArray)}')
print(f'smallArray shape: {np.shape(smallArray)}')
smallArray = smallArray.flatten()
print(f'smallArray flattened: {np.shape(smallArray)}')
smallArray = np.reshape(smallArray, (200,30,20))
print(f'smallArray reshaped shape: {np.shape(smallArray)}')
```

[image]

PD:
I'm not sure slicing the big array is a good Idea, because then you are going to keep an array of smaller arrays to reshape it afterwards, consider leaving it and try:

```
smallArray = bigArray[i*200:(i+1)*200]
```